# C#: Alter numbers inside the textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, numbers, alter

I'm making a text to speech program and so far I have a textbox containing what should be said. However, I would like the program to say the numbers inside the textbox one at a time. For example the textbox may contain this:

"This is a number 3820 This is another number 3823"

I want the program to say the number seperately such as "This is a number Three Eight Two Zero". The text to speech server will break the numbers up seperately only if there are commas in between. So instead the textbox should have this:

"This is a number 3,8,2,0, This is another number 3,8,2,3,"

Also, is there a way to search numbers after a word and change that number. For example only change the numbers after the word "Account"? Example:

"This is an account 3029 This is a number 3009 This is another account 3030"

to

"This is an account 3,0,2,9, This is a number 3009 This is another account 3,0,3,0,"

Answer (score 2):

Split along spaces and other whitespace, then you can check if each word is a number.

Then you can convert that word into characters, add in commas, then put it back in.

Ideally, if your text-to-speech solution supports it, copy this back into a hidden text field, then use that for the speech, so the user doesn't see the modification.

You may want to just use tryParse though, for simplicity:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

```
bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
```

Where value is a `String`.

**Update**

After reading the edit to the question, by splitting into words, then start with converting the string to lower-case, so you can easily compare, then, just loop through each word.

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for(int t = 0; t < wordarray.length - 1; t++) {
  String s = wordarray[t];
  if (numberWord.contains(s) && isWordNumber(wordarray[t + 1]) {
      s = addCommas(wordarray[t + 1]);
  }
  buf.append(' ').append(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered a simple string.Replace? i.e.

```
myText = myText.Replace("1", "1,");
```

Repeat for each number

Also do you need to edit the text box, can't you just process the text (taken from the text box) before sending it to the text to speech utility?

Comment: That works and was probably a bad mistake on my part for not realizing. My question next (I forgot to add this to the original question, which I will edit now) is how can I edit some numbers while leaving the rest unchanged? Such as "This is an account 3029 This is a number 3009" and I want it as "This is an account 3,0,2,9, This is a number 3009"? That was the more important question.

Comment: How do you tell the numbers apart i.e. which one to modify and which one to not. If just the first number then James Black's answer could be used to find the first number and then do the string replace as suggested.

Comment: The numbers are altered depending on the previous word. For example only numbers after the word "account" would be changed. So is there a way to find the word "account", then if the next character is a number, add a comma to it and keep doing that until the character is not a number?

Comment: Then I'd say go with string.Split -> iterate to the word account check if next entry is a number -> parse it using string.Replace (or a regular expression) -> use string.Join to merge it all back

Answer (score 1):

This method will parse the numbers and put them in comma delimited format:

```
public string ParseNumbers(string expression)
{
    return string.Join(",", System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(expression, "[^\\d]"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event(e.g KeyPress) handler to the text box.

```
TextBox1.KeyPress +=
                new KeyPressEventHandler(TextBox1_KeyPress);

void TextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
//do your check here.
}
```